# Extracting Gmail username with OAuth access token

Tags: oauth, gmail, imap

I'm using OAuth to get a user to grant me access to their Gmail IMAP account. I can successfully get an access token, and need to know what endpoint I can access to get the authenticated user's e-mail address.

Comment: if you found any answer , please share it with us.i am having the same question. thanks

Answer (score 4):

And you can test this feed using Google's [OAuth Playground](http://googlecodesamples.com/oauth_playground/index.php), as I just did.

In step one, paste the scope:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo#email
```

And in step six, paste the feed URI:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/email
```

This should help in adapting the feed for use in your own application.

Comment: When set the scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo#email, another scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.m will be added automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can get user's username and email with endpoint: https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/email with scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo#email.