# How can I get the username or email address from oauth?

Tags: android, oauth, gmail

I'm using the oAuth in my android application to log in into it. I would like to extract the username or email address after successfull logging in? Is there any way to do it? If yes - how?

I found this: [Extracting Gmail username with OAuth access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794715/extracting-gmail-username-with-oauth-access-token)  but really don't know how to use it

Comment: How do you get the OAuth token in the first place? If you are receiving it from some fourth party application then please ignore this comment. Otherwise, you need to generate the token *from* the user's credentials. [The tutorial in the android docs](http://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate.html#RequestToken) should help you do that. The examples cover gmail so should be useful for you. If you're just starting with OAuth, [this guide](http://hueniverse.com/oauth/) really helps you get your head around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I digg the internet till its end and I come up with this:

```
 private String usernameReader() {
        String jsonOutput = "";
        try {
            jsonOutput = makeSecuredReq(Constants.API_REQUEST, getConsumer(this.prefs));
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonOutput);
            JSONObject m = (JSONObject) jsonResponse.get("feed");
            JSONObject email = (JSONObject) m.get("id");
            jsonOutput=email.getString("$t");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("errroro", "Error executing request", e);
            //  console.setText("Error retrieving contacts : " + jsonOutput);
        }
        return jsonOutput;
    }

    private String makeSecuredReq(String url, OAuthConsumer consumer) throws Exception {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
        Log.i("Requesting", "Requesting URL : " + url);
        consumer.sign(request);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
        Log.i("statusLine", "Statusline : " + response.getStatusLine());
        InputStream data = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(data));
        String responeLine;
        StringBuilder responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((responeLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            responseBuilder.append(responeLine);
        }
        // Log.i(C.TAG,"Response : " + responseBuilder.toString());
        return responseBuilder.toString();
    }

    private OAuthConsumer getConsumer(SharedPreferences prefs) {
        String token = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
        String secret = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, "");
        OAuthConsumer consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
        consumer.setTokenWithSecret(token, secret);
        return consumer;
    }
```

it is just slightly modified version of this http://androidwarzone.blogspot.com/2011/07/android-oauth-full-example-with-source.html

nevertheless, thank You William Carter for your time and effort.